# React app crashing when react-router is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react app that works great on localhost.
after deploying, I upload the build folder content and the app crashes.
this is the crush screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/hjkoBmaY9 just a white screen. 
I have searched a lot and found that it is caused by the `react-router-dom`

this is my `App.js` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Calc from './components/Calc';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import MechinaSetup from './components/adminarea/MechinaSetup';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Calc}  />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/mechinasetup" component={MechinaSetup} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

if I remove the `BrowserRouter` block and run the build again, I see the app,

this is how I see an output

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Calc from './components/Calc';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import MechinaSetup from './components/adminarea/MechinaSetup';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // <BrowserRouter>
      //   <Route exact path="/" component={Calc}  />
      //   <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      //   <Route path="/mechinasetup" component={MechinaSetup} />
      // </BrowserRouter>
      <Calc />
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

What can be the reason to that?

here is the git repo of the project.
https://github.com/davsev/calc

any help would be amazing.

Comment: Is there an error in the Developer Tools console when you get a white screen? What URL are you hosting your live app at? You might have to set the [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) on the `BrowerRouter`.

Comment: Alright. Try to set the `basename` to `/calc`. `<BrowserRouter basename="/calc">...</BrowserRouter>`

Comment: also `BrowserRouter` needs to have a single child, you could wraper your `Route` lines with the `Switch` component

Comment: @OlivierBoissé when I try to do waht you suggested I get this error:
`Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>
`

Comment: you should add `<Switch>` inside `<Router>` like that `<BrowserRouter><Switch><Route/>...</Switch></BrwoserRouter>`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.

Quick Troubleshoot -

1. Make sure that the components in your Route definitions do not have a duplicate of the Switch Route definition or any for that matter.
2. Keep all your Route definition in the App js file
3. Wrap the  with the BrowserRouter in the index.js file. Take it out of the App.js